# Calling anonymous javascript function in swift using JSContext

Tags: javascript, swift

I found how you can call named javascript functions in swift using JSContext. Like this:

```
let context = JSContext()
context.evaluateScript("function sum(a,b) { return a+b; }")
let sumFunction = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("sum")
let result = sumFunction.callWithArguments([5,3])
println("Sum = \(result.toInt32())")
```

However, how can I call an anonymous javascript function given to me as

```
(a,b) { return a+b;}
```

Note the "sum" functionname is missing, hence anonymous, this is correct javascript syntax

Comment: you would not be able to call this function in javascript as well unless you assign it to a variable. thus the function will not be stored to the contexts' globalObject and cannot be called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Christian's feedback, I figured out a solution to my problem by assigning it to a variable like this :

```
    //this is the function that was passed to us that needs to be executed
    let givenJavaScriptFunction="function (a,b) {return a+b;}"
    //because the given function string does not contain a name
    //we add it to a variable " var sum = function price(a,b)..."
    let namedFunction = "var sum = " + givenJavaScriptFunction
    //create context
    let context = JSContext()
    //create conext
    context.evaluateScript(namedFunction)
    //get ref to our  function
    let function = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("sum")
    //call the function with the arguments
    let result = function.callWithArguments([10,7])
    //return value
    return result.toDouble()
```

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
import JavaScriptCore
let context = JSContext()
let value : JSValue = context.evaluateScript("(function (a,b) { return a+b; })")
let result = value.invokeMethod("call", withArguments: ["this",1,2])
print(result.toInt32())
```

Comment: this requires the function to be wrapped in (....) and then indeed it does work. I have deviced a similar solution by using var = function... see below which I prefer because it makes actually calling the function in swift a bit more clear (use name of the var instead of "call" with this...)